# Sentinel-2 Level 2A clouds removal

Tags: sentinel-2, cloud-cover, sentinel-snap, qgis-cloud

I tried to remove clouds from Sentinel-2 imagery (Level 2A) using ESA SNAP. I use SNAP 9.0.0. I tried to follow the tutorial "Automatic cloud Masking of Sentinel 2 Imagery Using ESA SNAP". But in my SNAP I couldn't find Idepix in ESA SNAP.

I need the imagery to be cloud free since I am carrying out a land use land cover classification.

I have attached documents for your reference.

How can I solve this matter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it via the menu **> Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > Install** first

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your support.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped in your case please mark my answer as the solution.